# When sorting an array, in case of identical values how to assign shared ordinal suffixes?

Tags: java

Weird title, stick with me:

I have a method that gives me an ordinal (whatever it's called) based on the int that is provided:

```
public String ordinal(int i) {
String[] suffixes = new String[] { "th", "st", "nd", "rd", "th", "th", "th", "th", "th", "th" };
switch (i % 100) {
case 11:
case 12:
case 13:
    return i + "th";
default:
    return i + suffixes[i % 10];
  }
}
```

So, `ordinal(1)` returns `1st`

Now the actual problem - I am using Comparator to sort objects based on one of their parameters:

```
public void sortClients(){
    sortedClients.addAll(clientList);
    sortedClients.sort(Comparator.comparing(Client::getScore).reversed());
    }
```

In the end I print them to the console like this:

```
int j = 1;
for (int i = 0; i < sortedClients.size(); i++) {
    System.out.println(ordinal(j) + " " + sortedClients.get(i).getName() + " - "
                    + sortedClients.get(i).getScore());
    j++;
    if (i == sortedClients.size() - 1) {
        j = 1;
    }
        }
```

This results in:

```
1st John Smith - 12.61
2nd Adam West - 13.43
3rd Roger - 13.43
4th That man - 13.75
```

My goal is to get this result:

```
1st John Smith - 12.61
2nd-3rd Adam West - 13.43
2nd-3rd Roger - 13.43
4th That man - 13.75
```

What sort of check do I have to do here to know when these clients have the same value (or do I somehow modify ordinal() instead)

Comment: why print the ordinal? the value of i is all you need to get the numbers right

Comment: You can iterate over the Clients and place them in a Map keyed on the score where the value is actually a List (e.g. `Map<Score, List<Client>>`).  Assemble a `List` of the elements in the key `Set` and sort it in the order you want to iterate.  For each key from the sorted `List`, get the associated `List<Client>` from the `Map`.  Using the count of that `List` you should be able to determine how to assemble the ordinal String.  You'll need an ordinal method that takes a range of values in some form.

Comment: In your example, Adam and Roger are tied with 2nd place.  There is no 3rd place.

Answer (score 0):

Change this second printing end part ("In the end I print them to the console like this:") to this code works:

```
    int j = 1;

    double nextScore = -1;

    for (int i = 0; i < sortedClients.size(); i++) {

        String ordinalStr = ordinal(j);

        // check for nexts
        if(i != 0 && i != (sortedClients.size()-1)) {

            if (nextScore == sortedClients.get(i).getScore()) {
                ordinalStr = "";

                int k = 0;
                for (; k < sortedClients.size() ; k++) {

                    if (sortedClients.get(i).getScore() == sortedClients.get(k).getScore())
                        break;
                }

                for (; k < sortedClients.size() ; k++) {

                    if (sortedClients.get(i).getScore() != sortedClients.get(k).getScore())
                        break;
                    ordinalStr += ordinal(k+1) + "-";

                }
                ordinalStr = ordinalStr.substring(0, ordinalStr.length()-1);
            }
        }


        System.out.println(ordinalStr + " " + sortedClients.get(i).getName() + " - "
                + sortedClients.get(i).getScore());
        j++;
        if (i == sortedClients.size() - 1) {
            j = 1;
        }


        if (i != (sortedClients.size()-1))
            nextScore =  sortedClients.get(i+1).getScore();

    }
```